# Creating a matched sample using some variables

Tags: stata, propensity-score-matching

My dependent variable is an indicator variable (1 or 0). The issue is that my N is very large but the number of observations where my dependent variable =1 is very small (only 3%) so when I run regressions my coefficients are very tiny. So I want to create a matched sample across some dimensions. I know I should use psmatch2,

I tried

```
psmatch2 depvar v1 v2 v3, common
```

but I only have very small number of "treated" and a large number of "untreated" pretty much what I had in my original data. I want to keep the observations where y=1, and only want to create a sample that consists of similar obs across v1, v2, v3 and I want this group to have reasonably similar number of obs.
Any idea?

Comment: This seems to raise more than programming issues. If you want advice on strategy as well as Stata, Statalist is a better venue than SO.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a matched sample, an alternative approach would be to consider quasi-matching techniques, such as entropy balancing and coarsened exact matching.

To implement entropy balancing in Stata, you can try something like below:

```
ssc install ebalance
ebalance treat_var v1 v2 v3, tar(2)
```

The above commands install the `ebalance` package and assign weights to each observation such that the mean and the variance of variables `v1, v2, v3` are roughly the same for treatment and control groups. Use `help ebalance` to find out more.

To implement coarsened exact matching in Stata, you can try something like the following:

```
ssc install cem
cem v1 v2 v3, tr(treat_var)
```

Both `cem` and `ebalance` generate a weight for each observation. The weight variables are stored in the dataset and named `cem_weights` and `_webal` respectively. To incorporate entropy balancing or coarsened exact matching into your regression analysis, simply estimate weighted regressions

```
regress y treat_var [aweight=_webal]
```